# Ajax - getElementById create text in multiple divs

Tags: html, ajax, getelementbyid

Hey guys and sorry for my bad english forwards.

I have this code:

```
<body>
    <div id="left">
    <p><a name = "container" value="topright" href="javascript:handleContent('topright')" onclick="loadContent('hallo1.php');">Hallo Welt 1</a></p>               
    <p><a name = "container" value="bottomright" href="javascript:handleContent('bottomright')" onclick="loadContent('hallo2.php');">Hallo Welt 2</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="topright"></div>
    <div id="bottomright"></div>
</body>
```

And Ajax:

```
    var xmlHttpObject = false;

if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') 
{
    xmlHttpObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
if (!xmlHttpObject) 
{
    try 
    {
        xmlHttpObject = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e) 
    {
        try 
        {
            xmlHttpObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e) 
        {
            xmlHttpObject = null;
        }
    }
}

function loadContent(id){    
    xmlHttpObject.open('get', id);
    xmlHttpObject.onreadystatechange = handleContent;
    xmlHttpObject.send(null);

    return false;
}

function handleContent(){
    if (xmlHttpObject.readyState == 4)

    {
        document.getElementById('topright').innerHTML = xmlHttpObject.responseText;
    }
}
```

If i click "Hallo Welt 1" i want to echo the Hallo1.php in top-right div.
So if i click "Hallo Welt 2" i want to echo the Hallo2.php in bottom-right div.
Something in my Ajax code is wrong. Please help me, im new :)

Thanks in forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is how you pass your arguments to handleContent.
The href="" currently doesn't do anything.
the solution is to pass "topright" or "bottomright" via a closure. That works like this:

```
(function (t){
    return function(){
        handleContent(t);
    }
})(target);
```

This creates a function that is directly called and returns a function which "bound" your argument (this is called a closure).

As I think your german:
Du musst dafür sorgen das deine Argumente richtig übertragen werden. Das machst du am einfachsten mit einem sogenannten Closure (eine Funktion die deinen Parameter in sich selbst speichert).

Solution (Tested in Firefox):

```
<body>
    <div id="left">
    <p><a name = "container" value="topright" onclick="loadContent('hallo1.php', 'topright');">Hallo Welt 1</a></p>               
    <p><a name = "container" value="bottomright" onclick="loadContent('hallo2.php', 'bottomright');">Hallo Welt 2</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="topright"></div>
    <div id="bottomright"></div>
    <script>

var xmlHttpObject = false;

if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') 
{
    xmlHttpObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
if (!xmlHttpObject) 
{
    try 
    {
        xmlHttpObject = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e) 
    {
        try 
        {
            xmlHttpObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e) 
        {
            xmlHttpObject = null;
        }
    }
}

function loadContent(id, target){    
    xmlHttpObject.open('get', id);
    xmlHttpObject.onreadystatechange = (function(t){return function(){ return         handleContent(t);}})(target);
    xmlHttpObject.send(null);

    return false;
}

function handleContent(target){
    if (xmlHttpObject.readyState == 4)

    {
        document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = xmlHttpObject.responseText;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```